# Converting ms word 2007 using poi

Tags: java, servlets, ms-word, apache-poi

What version of apache poi scratchpad can i use for both 2007 and 2003 format.Now am using poi-scratchpad-3.8 but it has only methods to convert doc file to html,pdf etc.But i need to use docx also which version of poi scratchpad have this functionaity?.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-examples -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```